# std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>> - is it OK?

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17, reference-wrapper

Is

```
std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<some_type>>
```

is conforming to the Standard (or draft) of C++17?

The Standard explicitly says, that `std::optional` for a reference type is ill-formed. But does it include `reference_wrapper`?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. That is OK. It does not include reference_wrapper because reference_wapper isn't a reference type. Only actual reference types are disallowed.

Comment: This could use a clarification, that 'it' refers to the standards ban on reference types in `std::optional`